# Skew image in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, skew

I want to skew an image in objective C like pictured below, is this possible using `CGAffineTransform`? I'm not sure how to achieve such an effect and so far only get it to rotate or scale.

[image: skew img]

Comment: m34 is the magic number, with some x rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `transform` property of a layer, since a layer's transform is a 3D transform.  In the code below, the anchor point of the layer is moved to the left edge, and then the 3D transform is applied. Note that `self.anim3DView` is just a standard `UIImageView`.

```
if ( self.anim3DView.layer.anchorPoint.x > 0.0 )
{
    CGPoint position = self.anim3DView.layer.position;
    position.x -= self.anim3DView.layer.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
    self.anim3DView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake( 0.0, 0.5 );
    self.anim3DView.layer.position = position;
}

CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t.m34 = -0.005;
t = CATransform3DRotate( t, M_PI / 6.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
self.anim3DView.layer.transform = t;
```